# How to change a variable in a Row in to a Column name with count in R

Tags: r

I am trying take a valuable from the rows and make them into columns in are.

[image: Unit Position count hospital fulltime 20 hospital parttime 100 hospital volunteer 50 Police fulltime 20 police parttime 5 police volunteer 10 fire fulltime 20 fire parttime 1 fire volunteer 5]

[image: Unit Fulltime Parttime Volunteer Total Hospital 20 100 50 170 Police 20 5 10 35 Fire 20 1 5 26]

Thank you all for your assistance

Comment: Hi Kit. This is known as reshaping your data from long format to wide format. It is a common data manipulation in R and has been answered many times before on Stack Overflow. There are are many ways to do it, and you will find some in the linked duplicate.

Comment: We could use `xtabs(count ~ Unit + Position, df1)` from `base R`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is pivot the data into wide shape this can be easily achieved with the `tidyr::pivot_wider` function, all you need to do is specify the columns from where the values will be taken and columns that contain the name for those values:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=Position, values_from=count)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Unit     fulltime parttime volunteer
  <fct>       <int>    <int>     <int>
1 hospital       20      100        50
2 Police         20       NA        NA
3 police         NA        5        10
4 fire           20        1         5
```

#### data

```r
read.table(text="Unit,Position,count
hospital,fulltime,20
hospital,parttime,100
hospital,volunteer,50
Police,fulltime,20
police,parttime,5
police,volunteer,10
fire,fulltime,20
fire,parttime,1
fire,volunteer,5", header=T, sep=',') -> df
```

One thing to keep in mind is when asking a question you need to provide the data in code form not in screenshots, one handy function to achieve this is the `dput` function after running `dput(data.f)` paste it to your question.